# Dúvida sobre recuperar dados do banco de dados

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, oracle, flask

Bom dia.

Sou iniciante em programação e tive uma oportunidade num projeto no trabalho para virar desenvolvedor. O projeto é somente um painel que mostra alguns dados do banco da nossa aplicação principal.

Estou em dúvida justamente em como recuperar estes dados do banco e utilizar como um objeto. Pelo que vi, o python recupera os dados do banco como uma tupla, utilizando o código abaixo:

```
sql_listar_pacientes = 'select nm_pessoa_fisica, nr_cpf, nr_identidade, to_char(dt_atualizacao) ' \
                       'from pessoa_fisica where cd_pessoa_fisica in (213117, 54879)'
c.execute(sql_listar_pacientes)
dados = c.fetchall()
```

Como faço essa tradução da tupla para um objeto em python?

Para explicar melhor:
Tenho um objeto Paciente e queria usar o resultado deste fetchall nos atributos deste objeto para após isto criar uma lista deste objeto e conseguir mostrar isto numa página web. É um projeto bem simples, mas não estou conseguindo passar o resultado do fetchall para este objeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, primeiramente parabéns e é importante depois desse projeto que comece primeiro estudando uma lógica de programação e depois estude a linguagem python, vai te ajudar bastante a seguir nessa carreira de programador.

Vamos a sua dúvida, primeiro, você não especificou qual seria o objetivo da busca (resultado do fetchall), vai ser um print desse resultado?, vai transformar em dicionário?, vai transformar em uma variável que irá separar os dados?

Não sabendo disso irei dar uma informação geral de como fazer, observe o código e tente entender como funciona, caso fique mais alguma dúvida edite seu post que eu responderei novamente.

Segue o código:

```
#Importo a biblioteca.
import sqlite3

#Faço a criação se não existente ou conecto ao banco de dados se existente.
db = sqlite3.connect('sqlite.sqlite3')

#Crio um cursor.
cursor = db.cursor()

#Crio uma tabela se não existente.
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Teste (nome TEXT, telefone TEXT, email TEXT)')

#Insiro os dados nessa tabela.
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Teste VALUES ("Pedrinho", "58747475", "pedrinho@exemplo.com")')

#Obtenho todos os valores onde o nome seja igual 'Pedrinho'.
info = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Teste WHERE nome="Pedrinho"').fetchall()

#Função seleciona o primeiro objeto da lista que retorna do fetchall()
#Em seguida seleciona cada elemento da tupla e carrega em uma variável
#O resultado disso: os dados separados por variável do tipo str (string) são retornados.
def separarPorVariavel(info):
    nome = info[0][0]
    telefone = info[0][1]
    email = info[0][2]
    return nome

#Função seleciona o primeiro objeto da lista que retorna do fetchall()
#Em seguida seleciona cada elemento da tupla e carrega em uma variável
#Em seguida cria e retorna um dicionario, que diferente da tupla é um objeto mutável.
def separarPorDicionario(info):
    nome = info[0][0]
    telefone = info[0][1]
    email = info[0][2]
    return {'nome': nome, 'telefone': telefone, 'email': email}

#Função cria uma lista vazia, em seguida percorre por cada elemento da primeira tupla resultado do fetchall()
#Em cada elemento percorrido é adicionada a lista criada anteriormente com o método append
#Em seguida retorna a lista dos objetos, a lista funciona igual a tupla mas é do tipo mutável.
def separarPorLista(info):
    lista = []
    for i in info[0]:
        lista.append(i)
    return lista
```

vamos ver também o comportamento dos outputs:

```
input: print(separarPorVariavel(info))
output: Pedrinho
```

```
input: print(separarPorDicionario(info)['nome'])
output: Pedrinho
```

```
input: print(separarPorLista(info)[0])
output: Pedrinho
```

Answer (score 0):

Python é uma linguagem onde a proposta é ter escrita clara, leve e ser muito produtivo. 


Tente entender as melhores práticas para Python, tanto para algoritmos (escrita) quanto para as estruturas de dados. 


Como você não especificou a base, ou eu falhei em observar, vou mostrar um exemplo para MySQL, sabendo que o SGBD não importa, pois o Python trata isso de forma transparente. 


Antes de mais nada, execute a linha de comando `python -m pip install mysql` para disponibilizar as bibliotecas para o MySQL.

```py
import mysql.connector  # Usado para estabelecer conexão com o Servidor MySQL.

server_ip = "[SEU_ENDEREÇO_DO_SERVIDOR]" # Sem os colchetes, é claro.
base_dados = "[SUA_BASE_DE_DADOS]" # Sem os colchetes, é claro.
usuario = "[SEU_USUÁRIO]" # Sem os colchetes, é claro.
senha = "[SUA_SENHA]" # Sem os colchetes, é claro.

query = "[SUA_QUERY_AQUI]" # Sem os colchetes, é claro.

try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=server_ip, database=base_dados, user=usuario, 
    passwd=senha)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    if cursor.rowcount > 0:
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
    else;
        print("Sem resultados para a query...")

except Error as e:
    print(e) # AQUI É SÓ PRA MOSTRAR O ERRO, SE HOUVER.

finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Você pode usar a classe `python_mysql_dbconfig`  para deixar a configuração mais amigável e oculta do código. Hardcoding não é muito bonito e essa classe ajuda nisso. 


Sugiro que você transforme essa estrutura de código em uma função que aceite a query e retorne uma estrutura de dados do Pandas: o DataFrame. 


Sugiro uma leitura do item https://stackoverflow.com/a/37730334/13123211 para ajudar na questão do DataFrame.


Para esta última aplicação você precisará instalar a biblioteca `pymysql` com o comando `python -m pip install pymysql`.


Sua aplicação ficará bem profissional.


Espero ter ajudado.